# Getting disposed object EnterpriseLibrary LogWriter error in Tasks loop

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, enterprise-library

Here is a sample program ( u will need Enterprise library to run it). I am running 100 Tasks in a loop, they log some message into event log.I store the generated Task in the Task array and simply monitor it inside a while loop.

Problem is out of 100 , random tasks fail and gives below error. From what I understand Task have their own state so they should not interfere with one another and the Logger method is static so I do not know where my Object is being Disposed.

1. Why is Logger object being disposed if its static ?
2. if I put LOCK(object) around my logger code inside Task.Run() than it works fine. Is this a good idea ?

**Error**

> at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.get_SyncLock()
>      at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.ExecuteReadOperation(Action readOperation)
>      at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.Write(LogEntry log)
>      at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(LogEntry log)
>      at WW.Test.TasksLoggingTest.b__1() in c:\tfs\Report\WWTest\TasksLoggingTest.cs:line 79
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace Test
{
    public class TasksLoggingTest
    {
        bool flag = true;
        Thread T;
        public static volatile bool IsWorkStarted = false;

        public void Start()
        {
            while(flag)
            {

                try
                {
                    if (IsWorkStarted == false)
                    {

                        IsWorkStarted = true;

                        T = new Thread(DoWork);
                        T.IsBackground = true;
                        T.Start();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error starting thread");
                }
                finally
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }
            }
        }


        public void DoWork()
        {
            try
            {

                Task<int>[] _tempTaskList = new Task<int>[100];

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    int localI = i;


                    _tempTaskList[localI] = Task.Run(() =>
                    {


                        Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);

                        var logEntry = new LogEntry
                        {
                            Severity = TraceEventType.Information,
                            Message = "Job Started :",
                        };

                        logEntry.Categories.Clear();
                        logEntry.Categories.Add("Send.To.EventLog");
                        Logger.Write(logEntry);


                        return 0;
                    });
                }


                bool IsAnyTaskPending = true;
                int noOfTasks = 0;

                while (IsAnyTaskPending == true)
                {

                    foreach (var t in _tempTaskList)
                    {
                        // Remove Completed Tasks from TaskList
                        if (t != null && t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                        {

                            Task<int> completedTask = t;
                            var temp = _tempTaskList.ToList();
                            //temp.Remove(t);
                            //_tempTaskList = temp.ToArray();
                            noOfTasks++;
                            //Console.WriteLine(" Completed");
                        }
                        else if (t != null && t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" Failed");

                        }

                    }

                    if (_tempTaskList.Length == 0)
                    {
                        IsAnyTaskPending = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("All {0} Tasks Done", noOfTasks);
                    }

                }

                IsWorkStarted = false;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you can't have two writers writing at exactly the same time to the log. You may need to synchronize access (as you've found out) to avoid contention. By the way, a lot of what you are doing can be done with continuations (complete or failed, etc) and `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Yeh seems like it...I do not want to do Task.WhenAll because in my production code we are doing something by monitoring the Status.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `Logger.SetLogWriter` is called for each task.  The internal `LogWriter` is a singleton.  However when you call `SetLogWriter` the current internal `LogWriter` is disposed:

```
    public static void SetLogWriter(LogWriter logWriter, bool throwIfSet = true)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(logWriter, "logWriter");

        var currentWriter = writer;
        if (currentWriter != null && throwIfSet)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.ExceptionLogWriterAlreadySet);
        }

        writer = logWriter;

        if (currentWriter != null)
        {
            currentWriter.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

So each task is disposing the singleton `LogWriter` which is pulling the rug out from under some other task.  The solution is to boostrap `SetLogWriter` once before invoking the tasks.

Comment: Hi Randy, can you explain further. What do you mean by bootstrap SetLogWriter ?

Comment: This is the code that is performing the bootstrapping: `Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);`.  Move this code to the beginning of the `Start` method instead of putting it in the thread.

Comment: @RandyLevy i would like to ask, if i am setting the logwriter at the beginning. The corresponding file is being 'locked' by the process. such that, i am unable to copy the file to my local. Is that a way to 'release the lock'?

Comment: @zeroflaw, Disposing the LogWriter will release the lock on the log file so that the file can be copied but after that you won't be able to log.  If you are trying to read the file programmatically you can read through the lock (since EntLib doesn't put a read lock on the file). e.g. `File.Open(path, FileMode.Read, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)`.

Comment: @RandyLevy Thanks for the information... by reading file programmatically, that means i have to somehow be able to access the filesystem + run a program >.< Or is that an easy way to read that file from Filezilla?

Comment: By the way, i have created a separate question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819716/how-to-release-logger-file-handler-when-using-with-enterprise-library).